# SQLite database export

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, backup, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to make simple app. In that i want to store database and export it in storage for backup. My code work properly on Android kitkat and lollipop but not make any database backup in Android marshmallow

```
public void copyAppDbToDownloadFolder(Context context) throws IOException {

    File backupDB = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "BackUpFolder.db"); // for example "my_data_backup.db"
    File currentDB = context.getDatabasePath("expense.db"); //databaseName=your current application database name, for example "my_data.db"
    if (currentDB.exists()) {
        Log.d("d", "copyAppDbToDownloadFolder--->>if condition<<<---");
        FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();

        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
        Log.d("s", "transform");
        src.close();
        dst.close();
    }
}
```

I used this method for export. I tried to find the problem in marshmallow but i couldn't. Anyone can help?

Comment: It's probably a permission issue, since permissions changed in Marshmallow.

Comment: You need to add runtime permissions in marshmallow to access the external storage. Have you added that?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  @IshitaSinha

Comment: @GauravLad Yes, this is the manifest permission, which you need in pre-marshmallow devices. You need to ask for permissions programmatically at run time in marshmallow. Let me know if [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) is not clear enough. Then I will post an answer.

Comment: so I have to write this code in dialogue box's true button? Only one time?@IshitaSinha

Comment: Plz post the answer. I got it why this is require. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: So, you actually don't know how to google for `android marshmallow permissions`?

Comment: I tried but I only get Dialogue box for permission. Now database is not saved in document folder( As my app's condition ). It is stopped from FileChannal line in the code.@Rotwang

Comment: I made it...Thanks @IshitaSinha@Rotwang

Comment: Hey Gaurav, really sorry for replying so late. Hadn't checked SO all day! Yes, you had to include that code in the positive button of your dialog. Glad you figured it out.